# How to use .NET XmlSerializer to serialzie null and empty value with special format

Tags: c#, xml

I want to use the .NET XmlSerializer class to serialize a class object to an XML string. both null string and empty string should be serialized.

if a property value is null then XML format like

```
<property />
```

if a property value is an empty string, then the serialized XML format is

```
 <property></property>
```

Comment: FYI, it's not the C# XmlSerializer. It's the .NET XmlSerializer. It is not specific to any language.

Answer (score 0):

When you need custom serialization, you'll need to implement your own implementation of the `IXmlSerialization` interface. This provides custom formatting for XML serialization and deserialization. For example :

```
public class Person : IXmlSerializable
{

    // Private state 

    private string personName;


    // Constructors 

    public Person (string name)
    {
        personName = name;
    }

    public Person ()
    {
        personName = null;
    }


    // Xml Serialization Infrastructure 

    public void WriteXml (XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteString(personName);
    }

    public void ReadXml (XmlReader reader)
    {
        personName = reader.ReadString();
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return(null);
    }


    // Print 

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return(personName);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have many classes need to serialize to XML. if use customize xml serialization,  will do a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use properties of class without initialize. It will like:

```
class XmlData{
    public string Person;
    public XmlData(){
          Person=null;
    }
}
class Program{
     static void Main(){
        var xmlTaplate=new XmlData();//in this step property Person is null    
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(xmlTemplate));

        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"person.xml"))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, details);
        }
     }
}
```